# Automatic backup of MySql DB daily based on scheduled time through Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to backup mysql DB from Java application (IDE Eclipse) based on schedule time(daily) but can't seem to find the file in the specified path. printing else part in the console, not getting where I am going wrong.. 
Please anybody help me out to resolve this.. Thanks in advance..

```
package com.cerner.automation.eboard.service;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UtilityService {

// Destination to create dump-date.sql file on daily basis
private static final String repo = "\"C:/DB_backup/dump-date.sql\""; //$NON-NLS-1$

/*
 * sec min hour(24) * & ? this is the syntax for daily job Here it is opted
 * to execute at 06:00 AM everyday
 */
private static final String CRON_MARIADB_DUMP = "00 00 18 * * ?"; //$NON-NLS-1$

@Scheduled(cron = CRON_MARIADB_DUMP)
public boolean dbBackup(String dbName, String dbUserName, String dbPassword, String path, String date) {
    String executeCmd = "mysqldump -u " + dbUserName + " -p" + dbPassword + "--add-drop-database -B " + dbName + " -r " + path; //$NON-NLS-1$//$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$ //$NON-NLS-4$
    Process process;
    try {
        System.out.println(executeCmd);// this out put works in mysql shell

        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", executeCmd }); //$NON-NLS-1$//$NON-NLS-2$
        // process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
        int processComplete = process.waitFor();

        if (processComplete == 0) {
            System.out.println("Backup created successfully"); //$NON-NLS-1$
            return true;
        }
        System.out.println("Could not create the backup");//$NON-NLS-1$

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").format(new Date());// $NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-1$

    UtilityService us = new UtilityService();
    us.dbBackup("root", "root", "eboard", repo, date); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
    System.out.println("Completed..."); //$NON-NLS-1$
}

}
```

this is the code, and when I run this, console printing like below..

```
mysqldump -u root -peboard--add-drop-database -B root -r "C:/DB_backup/dump-date.sql"
Could not create the backup
Completed...
```

Comment: Looks like permission issue, have you tried to backup to another drive instead of C:/

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well still it saying the same..

Comment: are you sure the path is correct. shouldn't it be "C:\\DB_backup\\dump-date.sql" or "C:\DB_backup\dump-date.sql" ?

Comment: actual path is "C:\DB_backup\dump-date.sql" but here its not allowing for "\" asking to change it for "/". but when I tried with "C:\\DB_backup\\dump-date.sql" also same problem

Comment: can you show the error?

Comment: put your code `private static final String repo = "\"C:/DB_backup/dump-date.sql\"";` into try and catch

Comment: showing error as "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )" when i am giving path as "C:\DB_backup\dump-date.sql"

Comment: use like this `private static final String DICTIONARY_FILE = "C:\\Users\\Sterling\\Documents\\FlashCards.tx t";`

Comment: tried, no changes. saying same..  mysqldump -u root -peboard--add-drop-database -B root -r "C:\DB_backup\dump-date.sql"
Could not create the backup
Completed...

Answer (score 0):

Could be the permission issue of the ID you are using to talk with MySQL.
However, you could dig deep if you add this `--verbose` in the mysqldump command. This enables the verbose mode and often helpful with the console logs.